# Linking local shared library with Waf (no lib compilation)

Tags: c++, compilation, sfml, waf

I'm trying to build a simple `c++11` program linking with a shared lib (dynamic library) using waf-1.8.8.

The particularity is that I'm not trying to build this lib, because I already have the dev version, which means the declarations (.hpp headers) and the definitions (`.so` files under `linux`, `.dll` + `.lib` under windows).

I am only trying to link like that:

```
$ g++ src/main.cpp -o mySFMLprogram.bin -std=c++11 -IthirdParty/SFML-2.2/include -LthirdParty/SFML-2.2/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window
```

That works very well from the base dir of my project.

What does not work is making this with a wscript / waf system... I don't find how to make the equivalent to  `-LthirdParty/SFML-2.2/lib`  (giving a new search dir to the linker, `man gcc` says `Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.`).

Here is the simplified tree of my project:

```
$ tree
.
├── src
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── wscript
├── thirdParty
│   ├── SFML-2.2
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── SFML
│   │   │       ├── Audio
│   │   │       │   └── **.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Audio.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Config.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Graphics
│   │   │       │   └── **.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Graphics.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Main.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Network
│   │   │       │   └── **.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Network.hpp
│   │   │       ├── OpenGL.hpp
│   │   │       ├── System
│   │   │       │   ├── **.hpp
│   │   │       │   └── **.inl
│   │   │       ├── System.hpp
│   │   │       ├── Window
│   │   │       │   └── **.hpp
│   │   │       └── Window.hpp
│   │   └── lib
│   │       ├── libsfml-audio.so -> libsfml-audio.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-audio.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-graphics.so -> libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-network.so -> libsfml-network.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-network.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-system.so -> libsfml-system.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-system.so.2.2.0
│   │       ├── libsfml-window.so -> libsfml-window.so.2.2.0
│   │       └── libsfml-window.so.2.2.0
│   └── wscript
├── waf
└── wscript
```

EDIT: update my files after @mkaes first explanation
The root `wscript` is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import os

VERSION = "0.1"
APPNAME = "wafTest"

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')

def configure(cfg):
    cfg.load('compiler_cxx')
    cfg.LIB_SFML = ['sfml-graphics', 'sfml-system', 'sfml-window']
    cfg.INCLUDES_SFML  = ['thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include')]
    cfg.LIBPATH_SFML   = ['thirdParty/SFML-2.2/lib')]
    cfg.check(
        features='cxx cxxprogram', 
        cxxflags=['-std=c++11', '-Wall'],
    )

def build(bld):
    bld.recurse('src')
```

And the `src` `wscript` is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

def build(bld):
    #EDIT removed bld(name = 'sfml-graphics', export_includes = '../thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include')
    #EDIT removed bld(name = 'sfml-window', export_includes = '../thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include')
    #EDIT removed bld(name = 'sfml-system', export_includes = '../thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include')
    bld.program(
        features='cxx cxxprogram', #is it an option ?
        source='main.cpp', 
        target='app', 
        use = ['SFML'], #first try> compilation error, headers missing
        includes = '../thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include' #second try> link error, lib missing
    )
```

Source code of `src/main.cpp` (easy it's taken from SFML basic test programs):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Previous output from waf command `./waf clean configure build`:

```
'clean' finished successfully (0.004s)
Setting top to                           : /home/***/Documents/dev/wafTest 
Setting out to                           : /home/***/Documents/dev/wafTest/build 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for compiler flags ['-std=c++11', '-Wall'] : yes 
'configure' finished successfully (0.070s)
Waf: Entering directory `/home/***/Documents/dev/wafTest/build'
[1/2] Compiling src/main.cpp
[2/2] Linking build/src/app
src/main.cpp.4.o: dans la fonction « main »:
main.cpp:(.text+0x10f): référence indéfinie vers « sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&) »
main.cpp:(.text+0x12d): référence indéfinie vers « sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) »
main.cpp:(.text+0x160): référence indéfinie vers « sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&) »
main.cpp:(.text+0x19b): référence indéfinie vers « sf::Window::close() »
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b4): référence indéfinie vers « sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&) »
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c8): référence indéfinie vers « sf::Color::Black »
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): référence indéfinie vers « sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&) »
main.cpp:(.text+0x1df): référence indéfinie vers « sf::Window::display() »
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ee): référence indéfinie vers « sf::Window::isOpen() const »
main.cpp:(.text+0x206): référence indéfinie vers « sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow() »
main.cpp:(.text+0x23f): référence indéfinie vers « sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow() »
main.cpp:(.text+0x270): référence indéfinie vers « sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow() »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/***/Documents/dev/wafTest/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'app' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140412749536784: cxxprogram main.cpp.4.o -> app}
['/usr/bin/g++', 'src/main.cpp.4.o', '-o', '/home/***/Documents/dev/wafTest/build/src/app', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
```

What's wrong?

EDIT2:
This example is SOLVED and can be found on Github: https://github.com/Tyrben/SFMLProjectUsingWaf 
Thanks @mkaes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to add your library during the configure phase. E.g

```
cfg.env.LIB_SFML = ['sfml-graphics', 'sfml-system', 'sfml-window']
cfg.env.LIBPATH_SFML = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'thirdParty/SFML-2.2/lib')]
cfg.env.INCLUDES_SFML = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include']
```

and then in your build just add `SFML` as a `use` directive.

**Update**:
Change your build to this:

```
def build(bld):
    bld.program(
        features='cxx cxxprogram', #is it an option ?
        source='main.cpp', 
        target='app', 
        use = ['SFML']
)
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work for me. I obtain many link error like `main.cpp:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to « sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow() »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
I will edit my post to show the wscript files.

Comment: Pretty strange as this works for me for the same use case. Can you also add the command line output from waf?

Comment: I have added the output.
ID : it says Waf: Entering directory `/home/nounours/Documents/dev/wafTest/build'   so maybe it hasn't all the lib headers and .so in the build subdir ?!

Comment: @Sandburg: I hope that if you change your build to the one I added, that it will work. This is exactly how I do it.

Comment: If in my `root configure` I put :

`cfg.LIB_SFML = ['sfml-graphics', 'sfml-system', 'sfml-window']

cfg.LIBPATH_SFML   = ['thirdParty/SFML-2.2/lib']

cfg.INCLUDES_SFML  = ['thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include']`

and in my `build` part (launched as recursive) I put:

`bld.program(

  features='cxx cxxprogram',

  source='main.cpp',

  target='app',

  use = ['SFML']
`
Then I have a compilation error, can't find headers `fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp`

But If I add in the build directives `includes = '../thirdParty/SFML-2.2/include'` now I have a link error (better).

Thats where I always stuck

Comment: It is stripped down but in general this is what I use in some of my projects. And I never encountered any problems with this. You could check the output if waf adds the correct flags to your build command, beside of this I don't have any Idea what your problem is.

Comment: @Sandburg: This is a little embarrassing but I forgot the env and I did not see it while writing this post. I changed the post and now your example works fine if you just use `cfg.env.LIB_SFML` and so on. BTW you don't need the includes in the build in your src directory.

Comment: Thank you @mkaer. It has solved my problem. I have also updated the test case on github.